# Unable to divide to counts of two separate lists in SQL, keeps returning 1

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one list of events. One event name is creating an account and another is creating an account with Facebook. I am trying to see what percentage of accounts created use Facebook.

The code below will give me an accurate count of the number of facebook accounts and total accounts, but when I try to divide the two numbers it just gives me the number 1.

I am very new to SQL, and have spent hours trying to figure out why it is doing that to no avail.

```
with
fb_act as (
  select * 
  from raw_event 
  where name = 'onboard_fb_success' 
    and event_ts::date >= current_date - 30
),
total_act as (
  select * 
  from raw_event 
  where name ='create_account' 
    and event_ts::date >= current_date - 30
)    
select count(fb_act)/count(total_act), total_act.event_ts::date as day
from total_act, fb_act 
group by day 
order by day
```

I expect the output to be about ~.3, but the actual output is always exactly 1.

Comment: if count(fb_act) == count(total_act) in result you will get 1 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional aggregation is a much simpler way to write the query.  You appear to be using Postgres, so something like this:

```
select re.event_ts::date as day,
       (sum( (name = 'onboard_fb_success' and event_ts::date >= current_date - 30):: int) / 
        sum( name = 'create_account' and event_ts::date >= current_date - 30)::int)
       ) as ratio        
from raw_event re
group by re.event_ts::date
order by day;
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! I am using postgres, I apologize, I should have tagged that.